# Get the params from angularjs in servlet

Tags: java, angularjs, servlets

mainController

```
    $scope.strings = {
    str1 : null,
    str2 : null,
    str3 : null
};
$scope.strings.str1 = "str1";
$scope.strings.str2 = "str2";
$scope.strings.str3 = "str3";


$scope.login = function() {
    var xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttpReq.open('POST', "http://localhost:8080/WEB-war/FES", false);
    xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    xmlHttpReq.send(JSON.stringify($scope.strings));
    if (xmlHttpReq.status === 200) {
        console.log("From controller: " + xmlHttpReq.responseText)
    }

}
```

servlet

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("inside do POST");
        Object obj = request.getAttribute("what to write here?");

 }
```

i need to get access to the scope.strings from angularjs

i sent it in the controler with this code i belive>

```
xmlHttpReq.send(JSON.stringify($scope.strings));
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should start to use the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) module of angular.

```
var url = "http://localhost:8080/WEB-war/FES";
var data = $scope.strings;

$http.post(url, data)
   .then(
       function(response){
         // success callback
       }, 
       function(response){
         // failure callback
       }
    );
```

Servlet should have something like

```
// example using the javax.json.stream package
JsonParser parser = Json.createParserFactory().createParser(request.getReader());
```

also see [Angular http POST to Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401581/angular-http-post-to-servlet)

Comment: JsonParser parser = Json.createParserFactory(<--eclipse generates null here and the other stuff is the same....so it does not work -.-

Comment: Well parsing a json is not the issue here, you can search other solutions.

You can see the Jackson library that is the one I use.

Back to the problem can you access data on post request? `request.getReader()` give what you need?

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes