# How to get form data into angular controller and how to pass it to serlvet?

Tags: java, angularjs

I have a form which contains two `<select>` tags.
One is a list of the year the other is a list of dosages.

When I select the options am able to get the `selectedYear` in my controller using ng-model but am not able to get `selectedDosage`.
And when am trying to send this data to my servlet it is returning null as a value.

Any suggestions I appreciate 
JSON

```
Dosages:[
    {"name":"Tablet"},
    {"name":"Syrups and Suspension"},
    {"name":"Non-Antibiotic Capsules"},
    {"name":"Antibiotic Capsules"},
    {"name":"Dry Powder for Suspension"},
    {"name":"ORS"},
    {"name":"Antiseptics"}
]
Years:{"json1":"[
    {\"years\":2018},
    {\"years\":2017},
    {\"years\":2016},
    {\"years\":2015}]"
```

HTML

```
<form  ng-submit="Display()">

    <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedYear">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Select Year</option>
        <option   ng-repeat="option in years" ng-value="{{option.years}}" >
          {{option.years}}
        </option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedDo">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Select Dosage</option>
        <option  ng-repeat="option in section" ng-value="{{option.name}}"  >
          {{option.name}}
        </option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>       
</form>
```

Controller

```
$scope.selectedDo;
$scope.selectedYear;
$scope.Display=function(){

    $window.alert($scope.selectedDo+"..."+ $scope.selectedYear);
    $http({
        method:"post",
        url:"/com.az.BusinessRatioAnalysis/SectionServlet",
        data:{
           year:$scope.selectedYear,
           dosage:$scope.selectedDo,
        }
    }).then(function(result){
        $window.alert("Ajex call failed" + result);                             
    });
};
```

Servlet

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String year=request.getParameter("year");
        String dosage=request.getParameter("dosage");
                System.out.println(year+".."+dosage);
    }
```

Comment: I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31402041/1848326) should help you.

Comment: still am getting the same problem @DeepakSharma

Comment: @Deepak Sharma Okay by this code ` String str;
         while((str=request.getReader().readLine())!= null){
             System.out.println(str);
             System.out.flush();
         }` `OUTPUT:-{"year":"number:2017","dosage":" Syrups and Suspension"}`

Comment: So is it working for you now or still facing issue ? As per your comment, you are able to get the json in the Servlet class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below.

Payload Bean class:

```
class Bean {
    Year year;
    Dosage dosage;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Servlet Class:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
    String str;
    while ((str = request.getReader().readLine()) != null) {
        json.append(str);
    }

    // Using Jackson
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Bean bean = objectMapper.readValue(json.toString(), Bean.class);

    System.out.println("Year ::" + bean.getYear());
    System.out.println("Dosage ::" + bean.getDosage());
}
```

pom.xml file in case of a maven project, else add jars accordingly:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

PS: Ignored Exception Handling in above code

Comment: am not able to get the data from the form that my primary issue Thank you for your effort @Deepak Sharma

Comment: @Minh: Can you confirm if the javascript function `Display()` is invoked on submit.

Comment: Yes, my display() method is working properly even the call to a servlet from my angular Controller but am getting this error `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input`

Comment: i tried by adding ` objectMapper.configure(Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE, true);` but still the same error

Comment: @Minh: can you please add the json here which you get in the Servlet doPost method.

Comment: am not getting any value and when i do throught `request.getParameter()` am geting null

Comment: My actual problem is in Angular Controller function the data is not going to the servlet even static data is not going to the servlet

Comment: @Minh: Can you try to use the code in your servlet which I have shared in my answer and debug the value of `json` variable.